# Build up object with nested objects C# - how to add lineitems to invoice

Tags: c#, object, nested, generic-list

I'm trying to build a list of Invoices, but each Invoice has a list of LineItems,
can I please ask guidance on how to add the nested objects.

I am battling to figure out who to add the LineItems to the Invoice as shown here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace myNS
{

    class Invoice
    {
        public int id;
        public int value;
        List<LineItem> li = new List<LineItem>();
    }
    class LineItem
    {
        public int LineItemID;
        public int LineItemValue;
        public int LineItemQty;
    }

    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var items = new[]
            {
            new Invoice{id=1, value =30}, //how to insert LineItems here
            new Invoice{id=2, value =10},
            new Invoice{id=3, value =20}
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your `List` needs to be public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated - your list needs to be public.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int id;
    public int value;
    public List<LineItem> li = new List<LineItem>(); //<-- here
}
```

This will allow you to access it.

To add an item to the list - you have two choises.

1) create a new list *on* initialization, and put the item in it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lineitem = new LineItem();
    var items = new[]
    {
    new Invoice{id=1, value =30, li = new List<LineItem>{lineitem}}, //<-- like this
    new Invoice{id=2, value =10},
    new Invoice{id=3, value =20}
    };
}
```

2) add the item to the existing list - *after* initialication:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lineitem = new LineItem();
    var items = new[]
    {
    new Invoice{id=1, value =30},
    new Invoice{id=2, value =10},
    new Invoice{id=3, value =20}
    };

    items[0].li.Add(lineItem);//<-- like this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this... notice li needs to be a public List

```
class Invoice
{
    public int id;
    public int value;
    public List<LineItem> li = new List<LineItem>();
}
class LineItem
{
    public int LineItemID;
    public int LineItemValue;
    public int LineItemQty;
}

class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new[]
        {
        new Invoice{id=1, value =30, li = new List<LineItem>{new LineItem{LineItemID = 1, LineItemValue =2,LineItemQty = 3}}}, //how to insert LineItems here
        };
    }

}
```